# Template adding to the page

Tags: templates, dashboard

I work for the client, made the site and now I'm editing the dashboard and I need help from you guys, I edited dashboard for the client that when they want to edit stuff, they can go on that account from original so they dont get lost in all plugins and stuff, and now I want that dashboard to be filled with templates for every page where they intend to publish more products, pictures and containers, and I looked all over the net and can't find the answer, I know js, but php not so much, so could I make that there is container on the dashboard that has template that looks like on the page but with placeholder images and text, and when they want to change it they edit it the same way I edit it and add to the page but from the dashboard and when they hit imaginary button that I guess needs to be connected to that page it publishes add the bottom of the last container, and for all that do I need special knowledge of php or what?

Thanks in advance!